# Merge data frame issue

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have 2 data frames ,

first one is

```
+------------------------------------------+
|       ID             CustomerType Choice |
+------------------------------------------+
| 0    1.0               Durability    OEM |
| 1    2.0                    Price    OEM |
| 2    3.0               Durability    OEM |
| 3    4.0               Durability    OEM |
| 4    5.0               Durability    OEM |
| 5    6.0  ManufacturerCredibility    OEM |
| 6    7.0                 Warranty    OEM |
| 7    8.0  ManufacturerCredibility    OEM |
| 8    9.0               Durability    OEM |
| 9   10.0                    Price    OEM |
| 10  11.0               Durability    TPN |
| 11  12.0                 Warranty    OEM |
| 12  13.0               Durability    TPN |
+------------------------------------------+
```

and second one is;

```
 --------------------------------------------------------+
|        Price  Durability  Warranty  Manufacture   Type |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| OEM     1.00         4.0       4.0          4.0    OEM |
| TPN     0.80         4.0       1.0          1.0    TPN |
| Reman   0.55         4.0       0.5          1.0  Reman |
| Reuse   0.45         2.5       0.0          1.0  Reuse |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to join these 2 data frames by using "Choice" from the first dataframe and "Type" from the second dataframe .

Currently I'm using

```
data = pd.merge(survey,rel_attr, left_on = 'Choice', right_on = 'Type',how='left')
```

and having awkward result like this.

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     Price  Durability  Warranty  Manufacture             CustomerType Choice |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0     1.0         4.0       4.0          4.0               Durability    OEM |
| 1     1.0         4.0       4.0          4.0                    Price    OEM |
| 2     1.0         4.0       4.0          4.0               Durability    OEM |
| 3     1.0         4.0       4.0          4.0               Durability    OEM |
| 4     1.0         4.0       4.0          4.0               Durability    OEM |
| 5     1.0         4.0       4.0          4.0  ManufacturerCredibility    OEM |
| 6     1.0         4.0       4.0          4.0                 Warranty    OEM |
| 7     1.0         4.0       4.0          4.0  ManufacturerCredibility    OEM |
| 8     1.0         4.0       4.0          4.0               Durability    OEM |
| 9     1.0         4.0       4.0          4.0                    Price    OEM |
| 10    1.0         4.0       4.0          4.0                 Warranty    OEM |
| 11    1.0         4.0       4.0          4.0                    Price    OEM |
| 12    1.0         4.0       4.0          4.0                 Warranty    OEM |
| 13    1.0         4.0       4.0          4.0  ManufacturerCredibility    OEM |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

From the result table we can see that all the rows contain OEM data from second dataframe. what im doing here wrong?

Comment: im new to programming , 
in my first dataframe index 10; custometype = Durability and Choice=TPN,
But in my result frame, index 10; customer type and choice is different.

it should be similar as 1st dataframe and price,durability, warranty and manufacture values also should be changed to TPN type  values as second table.
Sorry for my english also.

Comment: Now understand, for me it working nice. What is your pandas version?

Comment: seems like its my bad,seems like sorted by price (min : max)
when I use
head() I can only see the OEM type since it has the highest value for price.
After I use print command i can see the other data in bottom.

Is there any way to stop sort while merge.
Thanks

Comment: I think `left join` not sorting output. It only append new columns.

Comment: For you it sorting?

Comment: But if use default inner join `data = pd.merge(survey,rel_attr, left_on = 'Choice', right_on = 'Type')` it sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a bit different output from your sample data, last and `3.rd` row from end is merge correctly, also `left join` does not sorting by merging columns:

```
data = pd.merge(survey,rel_attr, left_on = 'Choice', right_on = 'Type',how='left')
print (data)
      ID             CustomerType Choice  ...   Warranty  Manufacture  Type
0    1.0               Durability    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
1    2.0                    Price    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
2    3.0               Durability    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
3    4.0               Durability    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
4    5.0               Durability    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
5    6.0  ManufacturerCredibility    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
6    7.0                 Warranty    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
7    8.0  ManufacturerCredibility    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
8    9.0               Durability    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
9   10.0                    Price    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
10  11.0               Durability    TPN  ...        1.0          1.0   TPN
11  12.0                 Warranty    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
12  13.0               Durability    TPN  ...        1.0          1.0   TPN

[13 rows x 8 columns]
```

If sorting it seems use `inner join` (default):

```
data = pd.merge(survey,rel_attr, left_on = 'Choice', right_on = 'Type')
#same as
#data = pd.merge(survey,rel_attr, left_on = 'Choice', right_on = 'Type',how='inner')
print (data)
      ID             CustomerType Choice  ...   Warranty  Manufacture  Type
0    1.0               Durability    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
1    2.0                    Price    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
2    3.0               Durability    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
3    4.0               Durability    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
4    5.0               Durability    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
5    6.0  ManufacturerCredibility    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
6    7.0                 Warranty    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
7    8.0  ManufacturerCredibility    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
8    9.0               Durability    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
9   10.0                    Price    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
10  12.0                 Warranty    OEM  ...        4.0          4.0   OEM
11  11.0               Durability    TPN  ...        1.0          1.0   TPN
12  13.0               Durability    TPN  ...        1.0          1.0   TPN

[13 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: @Yikes - OK, so question is need left join or inner join? In my opinion difference with nice samples is explain in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra)

Comment: Thanks, will read it soon. In my case both join doing the same thing i need to. only problem is sorting issue.
thanks gain